# SonarQube Coverage for the unit testing project is 0

Tags: c#, sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarscanner

I have used SonarQube for the code quality of the project written in c# Visual Studio.

The solution in the Visual Studio has Two Projects (Employee and TestEmployee). Employee is the web API project and TestEmployee is the unit testing for the Employee Project.

In SonarQube only Employee Project is Analyzed but not the TestEmployee Project.

The Coverage report is zero(o). The .cs in TestEmployee are not at all showing in the SonarQube.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the question is. The code coverage tool shows how much of the *actual* project's source code was covered by the tests executed by the unit project.

Comment: It is showing the code coverage as 0.00% even after the unit test project is been added.

Comment: Check if the code coverage file is generated. SonarQube only imports the results file it doesn't generate that file itself.